# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64, C++

Tags: c++

I am compiling a program in which I create a table.h file and table.cpp implementation of the methods. I am compiling on macOS with command: `g++ -std=c++1z -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -O3 db.cpp -o db`, but I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "Table::insert_row(Row*)", referenced from:
      execute_insert(SQLCommand*, Table*) in db-41330e.o
```

Here's the implementation of `insert_row`:

```
class Table {
    private:
    ...
    public:
    ...
    void* insert_row(Row*);
    ...
};

void* Table::insert_row(Row* row) {
    if (num_pages >= table_size) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (pages.empty()) {
        Page* page = new Page();
        pages[num_pages++] = page;
    }
    Page* page = pages[num_pages - 1];
    if (page->is_full()) {
        page = new Page();
        pages[num_pages++] = page;
    }
    void* row_ptr = page->insert_row(row);
    if (row_ptr == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Error: Page is full." << std::endl;
    }
    return row_ptr;
}
```

and `execute_insert`:

```
void execute_insert(SQLCommand* cmd, Table* table) {
    Row* row = new Row(stoi(cmd->args[0]), cmd->args[1], cmd->args[2]);
    void* row_ptr = table->insert_row(row);
    if (row_ptr == nullptr) {
        cout << "Error: Table is full." << endl;
        return;
    }
    delete row;
}
```

Comment: Is the `Table::insert_row` function defined (implemented) in the `db.cpp` source file, or another source file?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , another source file (table.cpp)

Comment: Did you compile and link with that file?

Comment: @PepijnKramer I included it in db.cpp using #include "table.h"

Comment: No you should not to that, NEVER include source files. You should tell your compiler to compile it seperately. And then you should link with it. Do you use a development environment, or cmake? Then use that

Comment: @PepijnKramer , I think I misinterpreted your question. I have defined all functions in "table.h" and implemented them in "table.cpp". Then, I included the "table.h" in the "db.cpp" file. So, I only included the header file. Should I also link headers using the compiler?

Comment: Change `... db.cpp -o db` to `... db.cpp table.cpp -o db` in your compile command... Including a _header file_ does not result in the compiler somehow _importing_ and compiling associated source code... Two `.cpp` files are two **separate** _translation units_

Comment: Time to learn about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). Basically, a translation unit is a *single* source file with all its included headers, and it's this "unit" that the compiler will work with. The compiler doesn't know anything about other source files or translation units. Then it's the job of the *linker* to take all translation units and libraries to generate the executable program. If you don't build with the `table.cpp` source file, the linker will not know about its translation unit.

Comment: Jargon lesson: "_defined functions in "table.h" and implemented them in "table.cpp"_" Not quite... Correct jargon '**declared** functions in "table.h" **defined** in "table.cpp"' Declaring provides the prototype(s); defining is the meat of the code...

Comment: Thank you! I really forgot that all .cpp files must be linked.

Comment: Not what you asked, but you should get into the habit of including parameter names (and not just their types) in your class declarations.  Your future self will thank you for it.